# How to get a value from a dictionary using other values

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I created a dictionary like this:

```
var TriangleRegistry = new Dictionary<string, TriangleRegistryObject>();
```

With a class like this:

```
class TriangleRegistryObject
{
    public double x1 { get; set; }
    public double y1 { get; set; }
    public double x2 { get; set; }
    public double y2 { get; set; }
    public double x3 { get; set; }
    public double y3 { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

The dictionary is filled with coordinates of triangles. Now, I know x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 and I want get the value of `Selected` of the right triangle using x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3.

Its important that I use all 6 values to find the 7th, because I got a lot of triangles!
Can someone help me?

Comment: Why use a dictionary if you are frequently retrieving them by criteria other  than that key?

Comment: What else should I use then? A list?

Comment: A List<T> should do the trick. Something like theList.Where(tro => tro.Selected).ToList();

Comment: HI,first want to know, where is the original data of `TriangleRegistryObject` from? And secocd want to know, why not when setting data to `TriangleRegistryObject` first time add the Selected's value? Last want to know, how is the detail logic of `TriangleRegistry`?

Comment: How many `Selected` triangles are usually in the dictionary? One or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store and retrieve something from a dictionary and the key is made up of all three coordinates of the triangle - six values - then the combined coordinates of the triangle *are* the key to the dictionary.

That's what you're describing here:

> I know x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 and I want get the value of Selected of the right triangle using x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3.

**(I'm sidestepping the question over whether a `Dictionary<TriangleRegistryObject, bool>` makes sense and focusing on how the points of a triangle could be used as a key.)**

Suppose you actually created a `Dictionary<TriangleRegistryObject, bool>` where the key was a triangle and the value was a boolean indicating whether it was selected or not. The challenge would still be that in order to determine whether a key is a duplicate or not, the dictionary would use reference equality. Two different instances of `TriangleRegistryObject` with identical coordinates could be two keys, which probably isn't what you want.

What we need is to tell the dictionary how to compare two triangles. We could do this by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `TriangleRegistryObject`. But instead of changing the class to meet the needs of this comparison we can just tell this particular dictionary how to compare triangles (although that might also be a perfectly good solution.)

First we would create a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer<TriangleRegistryObject>`:

```
public class TriangleComparer : IEqualityComparer<TriangleRegistryObject>
{
    public bool Equals(TriangleRegistryObject x, TriangleRegistryObject y)
    {
        return x.x1.Equals(y.x1) 
               && x.y1.Equals(y.y1) 
               && x.x2.Equals(y.x2) 
               && x.y2.Equals(y.y2) 
               && x.x3.Equals(y.x3) 
               && x.y3.Equals(y.y3);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TriangleRegistryObject obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = obj.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ obj.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

(Okay, that doesn't look so simple. I actually cheated and let Resharper help me to generate all that.)

Now, if we want to use the triangle as the key in the dictionary, we would just specify that comparer when creating the dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<TriangleRegistryObject, bool>(new TriangleComparer());
```

Now the dictionary will compare keys the way we've told it to instead of using reference equality.

Or, if you just wanted to add the equality comparison directly into the triangle itself instead of using a custom comparer, you could do this (which leaves out the `Selected` property):

```
public class TriangleRegistryObject
{
    public double x1 { get; set; }
    public double y1 { get; set; }
    public double x2 { get; set; }
    public double y2 { get; set; }
    public double x3 { get; set; }
    public double y3 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    protected bool Equals(TriangleRegistryObject other)
    {
        return x1.Equals(other.x1) 
            && y1.Equals(other.y1) 
            && x2.Equals(other.x2) 
            && y2.Equals(other.y2) 
            && x3.Equals(other.x3) 
            && y3.Equals(other.y3);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = x1.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ y1.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ x2.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ y2.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ x3.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ y3.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

There's still one catch: Presumably the points of triangle don't change. If they could change then bad things could happen. Let's say you have two different points used as keys, and then the points of one are changed to be the same as the points of another. Then you would have duplicate keys, which would be bad.

To protect against that you would make your triangle class immutable so that the values are passed to the constructor and can never be changed.

---

Just to cover the bases, since I don't know any specifics of your application: If your triangle is a struct instead of a class and all of its members are value types then the comparisons will be made using values. If the only values are the points (you remove `Selected`) then two instances with identical points would be considered equal and you wouldn't need all the extra comparison code. You would still want to make the struct immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using LINQ (as posted above/below) or for each loop and check wash variable. In most cases LINQ is slower alot so if your application requires a better performance - consider using for each / etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use LINQ to query your dictionary and find a match:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var matches = TriangleRegistry.Where(t => t.Value.X1 == ... && t.Value.Y1 == ...); // fill in the blanks here with whatever you're looking for
foreach (var match in matches)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Here's a match: {0}", match.Selected);
}
```

Comment: 'KeyValuePair<string, TriangleRegistryObject>' does not contain a definition for 'x1' and no accessible extension method 'x1' accepting a first argument of type 'KeyValuePair<string, TriangleRegistryObject>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: How can I fix this?